# Xamarin Forms MvxListView is populating with data, but the Binding at the MvxTextCell Is not showing Text

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

Prefacing this by saying I am by no means a Xamarin dev, and am just trying to add to an existing project.

I have a List View that is adding getting data added to it via an entry and button, and it is definitely updating the List View, because it is adding a new row every time, and it is properly being added to the ObservableCollection, but for some reason the text is just not showing up.

**XAML**

```xml
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:model="clr-namespace:App.Entites"
                 xmlns:mvx="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
                 xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
                 xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:App.ViewModels"
                 x:DataType="vm:MyViewModel"
                 x:Class="App.Views.MyView">
    <Grid Padding="20"
          BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=White, Dark=DarkGray}"
          HorizontalOptions="Center"
          VerticalOptions="Center"
          WidthRequest="250"
          HeightRequest="400">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="List Title" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Large" />

        <mvx:MvxListView x:Name="ListName" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
            <mvx:MvxListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <mvx:MvxTextCell Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="Black"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </mvx:MvxListView.ItemTemplate>
        </mvx:MvxListView>
        
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Center" Spacing="10">
            <Entry Placeholder="New Item" WidthRequest="250" Text="{Binding NewItem}" x:Name="NewDest" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"/>
            <Button Text="Add Item" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" Style="{StaticResource BlueButton}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

**View Model**

```cs
private ObservableCollection<string> _myList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> MyList
{
    get
    {
        return _myList;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_myList != value)
        {
            _myList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(_myList));
        }
    }
}

private string _newItem;
public string NewItem
{
    get { return _newItem; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _newItem, value); }
}

private MvxCommand showListCommand;
public IMvxCommand ShowListCommand
{
    get
    {
        showListCommand ??= new MvxCommand(ShowList);
        return showListCommand;
    }
}

private void ShowList()
{
    PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new MyListView(this));
}
public IMvxCommand<string> AddCommand => new MvxCommand<string>(AddItem);

private void AddItem(string item)
{
    MyList.Add(_newItem);
    NewItem = string.Empty;
}
```

Here is what the output looks like (I changed some of the names of labels and what not in the code, but the issue is the same:

[image: List Issue]

I have tried using an object and accessing the 'Name' attribute. I am expecting the text to fill in the blanks. (Below is an example with constant Text instead of a Binding)

[image: Example]

Even in this example when I add a destination it will add a new row into the list, and when I check the ObservableCollection it is also getting updated.

Comment: does this code even compile?  `MyList.Add(newItem);` - you have no variable named `newItem`.  And `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(_myList));` is wrong, you should use the name of the public property, not the private field.  These may not be related to the problem you're asking about, but when the posted code does not appear to be valid its hard to focus on the underlying question

Comment: After adding items, examine elements of MyView, make sure they are not blank. If they are, figure out why. Maybe related to NewItem vs newItem vs _newItem; please fix the code in question.

Comment: @Jason, sorry i had to try to change some field names when posting it due to them being company specific. If i made some mistakes that's my bad. I'll try the property change difference.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, I will fix the code now and try that. sorry I had to make adjustments to the code to make it more generic.

In the ListView I set SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" and the output of the selection and was working as expected. It seems to just be an issue with the actual text of the TextCell, but I'm not sure on how to actually troubleshoot that.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at end of AddItem, and examine elements of `MyList`, are they what you expect each time? To be sure something isn't wrong there.